# Forced hot air and mini heat pump

Tags: heating, forced-air, mini-split

I recently bought a house and I have forced hot air currently. It works fine, the only issue I have with it is that it constant turns on and off. I've been looking into mini heat pumps and they seem pretty nice (the whole ductless aspect). So I was wondering if anyone has experimented with using both? I was thinking of adding one mini heat pump for each unit (it's a multi family) not only as a backup, but to keep the forced hot air from turning on and off so often. Any ideas on how efficient/practical this might be?

Comment: Is the forced hot air gas or electric. Big savings with heat pump over electric , will need both on really cold days. If gas heat hard to beat that but most heat pumps have a reversing valve to become an AC unit in the summer.

Comment: a little bit confused about that question, the furnace uses gas to heat the air but need electricity to run..

Comment: The real question here should be if your heating system is cycling too often or needs maintenance. Also watch out for energy cost differences, in my part of the world it's much cheaper to heat with gas than electric.

Comment: The electric is just for the blower and thermostat, ignighter with a gas furnace. The heat is created by burning the gas that is where the cost is. Gas heat is hard to beat in the winter unless a geo thermal heat pump that uses ground water instead of emergency electric heat coils when it gets two cold. There are all electric forced air furnaces some heat pumps are Basicly electric forced because they use large electric heaters when the temps are two cold. Hope that helps to clear my earlier comment up.

Comment: it definitely does, this makes me feel a lot better about having what I do, I'll have to see what I can do to make the forced hot air a bit more efficient...

Comment: @Tyson I'll have to see if gas is cheaper here, thanks for the tip!

Comment: A forced air furnace is supposed to cycle on and off; there is nothing wrong with this. If the rooms are comfortably warm, then adding a ductless heat pump would be an unnecessary expense. It would provide a back-up heating system, but at a great expense.

Answer (score 3):

It'll work well as long as your mini split unit isn't conditioning the area near the thermostat for the forced hot air unit. If they're too close together, the mini split will make the forced air thermostat think it's always the perfect temperature, so it will never call for heat, and the rest of your rooms will never be comfortable.

The added expense of adding a mini split to multiple units is probably going to be a lot more than having someone fix the problem of the forced air unit constantly turning off and on. Running the circulation fan for 35%-100% of the time in the heating season might be a good and much more inexpensive solution without looking into it further.